# ffmpeg date time overlay without vhook

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to put current date and time on a video with ffmpeg (overlay).
Date and time must increase (16:10, 16:11, 16:12 ...) in sync with real time.
With vhook I can use a text file with %d and so on..

As vhook is no more present in the newer versions of ffmpeg, how can I obtain the same result?

Comment: There is a good tutorial [here](http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/)

Answer (score 2):

You can now use libavfilter :

http://www.ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html

From ffmpeg :

> Libavfilter is the filtering API of FFmpeg. It is the substitute of the now deprecated 'vhooks' and started as a Google Summer of Code project.

Good luck ;)